# How to convert '01-Jan-2022 05:17:13 PM CST' into datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

Want to know how can I convert '01-Jan-2022 05:17:13 PM CST' which is string format to datetime in sql server

Convert is not working

Comment: CST - as in Cuba Standard Time, or China Standard Time? https://24timezones.com/time-zones

Comment: Contral Time Zone

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Ideally, convert this from a string into a datetime value *well away from the database* and only pass it to the database as a properly typed parameter. There's no real reason you should be doing input cleansing in the database.

Comment: Try `CAST(SUBSTRING('01-Jan-2022 05:17:13 PM', 1, 23) AS datetime)`. Store the data in a properly typed column (`datetime`, `datetime2`, or `datetimeoffset`) to avoid the need to convert.

Comment: @DanGuzman Style 106 probably wise? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles

Comment: @Charlieface, I see no harm with `CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING('01-Jan-2022 05:17:13 PM', 1, 23), 106)`